# Another way to solve $y=-\frac1{x^2y'}-xy'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is seen that this is a differential equation which can be written as $y=f(x,y')$, and so I solve the equation as follows:

**My solution:**

$1- $ Using the substitution $z=y'$ which leads to $y=-\frac1{x^2z}-xz\ \ \ \ (*)$.

$2-$ deriving in terms of $x$ and then solving the new equation which is related to $x$ and $z$ with solutions $$(I)\ z=\pm \frac1{x^{3/2}}\ \text{and }\ (II)\ z=\frac c{x^2}. $$

$3-$ Replacing the obtained answers $(I)$ and $(II)$ to $(*)$ leading to $$ (I)\ y^2=\frac4x\ \ \text{and}\ \ \ (II)\ y=-\frac1c-\frac cx.$$

**My question:** Is there another technique to solve such a differential equation?

Answer (score 2):

multiplying with $$x^2y'$$ we get $$x^3y'^2+x^2y\cdot y'+1=0$$ dividing by $$x^3\ne 0$$ we obtain
$$(y')^2+\frac{y}{x}y'+\frac{1}{x^3}=0$$
solve this equation for $$y'$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(y')^2+\frac{y}{x}y'+\frac{1}{x^3}=0$$
Let $y=\frac{u}{x} \quad\to\quad y'=\frac{u'}{x}-\frac{u}{x^2}$

$\left(\frac{u'}{x}-\frac{u}{x^2}\right)^2+\frac{u}{x^2}\left(\frac{u'}{x}-\frac{u}{x^2}\right)+\frac{1}{x^3}=0$

After simplification : $\quad xu'^2-uu'+1=0$
$$u=xu'+\frac{1}{u'}$$
This is the well known Clairaut's ODE which solution is : $\quad u=cx+\frac{1}{c}$
$$y=\frac{u}{x}=c+\frac{1}{cx}$$